# Combine two unload files

Tags: sql, perl, unix, informix

I have two unload files like `header.unl` and `store.unl`.
`header.unl` contains only the column names of the table whereas `store.unl` contains output information from the table.

For example:

```
header.unl --> store_nbr country_code state_code

store.unl  --> 100 US 15
```

Now I want to combine both the files so my output should be like below:

```
store_nbr country_code state_code

100       US           15
...       ....         ....
....      ....         ....
```

Also I would like to get this in email.

Any ideas and help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried?  Is there a line in header.unl for every line in store.unl?

Comment: `cat header.unl store.unl` and pipe it to an appropriate mail program?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of under-specified details in the question.  For example, are the columns in the unload files separated by blanks, tabs or pipes (the Informix UNLOAD format default separator) or something else?  Does the email need to contain aligned data or not?  Is the blank line between the header and the data intentional?  Will your data ever contain the delimiter (because dealing with escaped delimiters greatly complicates reformatting the data).

The basic answer is to use `cat`:

```
{
cat header.unl
echo
cat store.unl
} | mailx -s "Stores Data" whoever@example.com
```

If the blank line isn't wanted, that simplifies to:

```
cat header.unl store.unl | mailx -s "Stores Data" whoever@example.com
```

If you need to format the data so it looks sane when presented in fixed-width font, then you probably need to run it through `awk`.

What is the person who receives the data going to do with it?  Would you be better off formatting the composite file as an attachment rather than as inline text (which is what they'd receive from the command above)?  If you need to do that, you might want to look at Perl email modules (there a many to choose from) to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what the question is about, what do you need beyond `cat`. I assume what you want is to replace spaces by tabs, but I might be confused (indeed I updated this post because my first answer was completely off-target, based on a wrong interpretation of your badly-formated question).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;


while( <>) { s{ }{\t}g; print ; }
```

you call this as `merge.pl header.unl store.unl`

as a one liner:

```
perl -p -e's{ }{\t}g' header.unl store.unl
```

Note that this is entirely untested, as I would not want to offend you by putting more effort into this than you did.

I am even less sure of what you mean by *"i would like to get this in email..."*, so I'll leave that part out.

Comment: How is this better than `paste`?  Anyway, I think the OP wants `cat`, not `paste`.

Comment: @tripleee would `paste` repeat the line from the first file?

Comment: oh, I see, the bad formating of the question let me to believe that the header needed to be repeated on each line of the output. Then `cat` is indeed the way to go.

Comment: No, that's right, there is a difference.  Still, I don't think that's what the OP wanted.

Comment: @tripleee I rewrote the code to do what *might* be what the OP wants. That'll be my last stab at this though, enough wasted time.